# How to redirect tab or access Mobx state from createTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobx

I want to recreate the modal that is initiated from the tabBar Button like on instagram. I have a global modal that can be called by changing the active state in mobx state tree and I have also blocked the tab transition for the targeted tab with this code below.

```
    const defaultGetStateForAction = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction;

AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if ((action.type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE) && (action.routeName === "postScreen")) {

        // Code to redirect to stack navigation or call modal here
        return null;
    }

    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

Here is where i get stuck.

1. is there a way to access my mobx store from here?
2. is there a way to do something like `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenYouWant')`

Comment: Is the main goal to able to navigate to a different screen?

Comment: well to access the store so i can call the modal, but if not that at least nav to another screen on the higher up stack navigator